# How to set fixed length for column in table?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I want to set fixed width to column and if table data is large then that column should be a scroll-able and if screen resolutions get changed then table also get scroll-able.

```
Example :

Name    Surname                                                       Salary

sam     jdfgdhfgdfgudfgiuudifghdfgjjdfhgjkhdfghkjdhfgjkhdfkjgkjdfhgk  5555
```

In above example Surname is large then table and column is not get responsive.

How to set fixed length for column with scroll-able property?
Table and column also be responsive to get executable in other screen resolutions.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: will help you https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content of the `<tbody>` in a scrollable `<div>` :

html:

```
...
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="scroll-table">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Sam</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>jdfgdhfgdfgudfgiuudifghdfgjjdfhgjkhdfghkjdhfgjkhdfkjgkjdfhgk </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5555</td>
          </tr>
...
```

css

```
.scroll-table{
     overflow:scroll;
    }
```